# How to configure tslint with curly braces always on their own line

Tags: indentation, tslint

Trying to figure out how to configure tslint to use Allman style bracing for class member objects.  Presently, I have tslint configured so that it is happy if I write

`const foo = () =>
{
};`

or if I do

`const foo = 
{
   a: 10,
   b: 20
};`

However, the moment I have a class and try to create a member in that class using the same style, tslint gets angry, and I cannot figure out how to make tslint accept both the above the following:

`export class Foo
{
    private someObj =
    {
        a: 10,
        b: 20
    };
}`

With the above, tslint will try to insist that the { a: 10, b: 20 } be indented one level.

It seems that I've been able to get part-way there by messing w/ the "ter-indent" rules of tslint.json.  If I set "VariableDeclarator" to 1, that's how I'm able to achieve what I want outside of classes.  However, there doesn't appear to be a "MemberDeclarator" setting.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: My understanding is that TSLint can only be used to enforce open braces being placed [on the same line](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/one-line/). I think you'd have to look for a custom rule to do what you want to do. Perhaps someone has written one.